# Filter duplicates on row_number results

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to make a query on PostgreSQL that gives me the top 10 jobs that take more time each month (excluding current month), I have made this query so far but it gives me duplicates on the job name. How can I filter these?

```sql
SELECT job, month, duration  
FROM (
    SELECT
    month,
    job,
    duration,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY month ORDER BY duration DESC) AS RN
FROM
    run_history
WHERE
    owner = 'john'
    ) x
WHERE RN <= 10
AND month < TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'yyyymm')
```

Comment: `the top 10 jobs that take more time each month` sounds ambiguous to me. You mean "the most time"?  Also, define "duplicate" for the task. Please lead with your Postgres version and a `CREATE TABLE` statement showing data types and constraints. (NULL values matter.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Sounds* like there can be multiple rows per `(owner, month, job)` and you want to work with the maximum duration per month for each job.

If so, aggregate computing `max(duration)` first, then use `row_number()` on top of it:

```
SELECT job, month, max_duration
FROM  (
   SELECT month, job, max(duration) AS max_duration
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY month ORDER BY max(duration) DESC NULLS LAST) AS rn
   FROM   run_history
   WHERE  owner = 'john'
   AND    month < to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'yyyymm')
   GROUP  BY month, job
   ) sub
WHERE  rn <= 10
ORDER  BY month DESC, rn;
```

Aside: consider `integer` or `date` instead of `text` for the column `month`: cleaner and more efficient.